# Replace a digit with another digit in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am writing a bash script in which I want to replace the first digit if 0 with 92 and if there is no 0 and 92 append 92 in front of that digit and save it in a new file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my bash script:

**scrap.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
file=test.txt
while IFS=, read -r field1
do
    echo $field1 | awk '$0*=1'>> test2.txt

done < $file
```

**test.txt**

```
03333333333
3848123249
```

**expected output**

```
923333333333
923848123249
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do add sample of your expected output also in your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your input file:

```sh
cat file

03333333333
92123456789
3848123249
```

You can use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E '/^92/!s/0|^/92/' file

923333333333
92123456789
923848123249
```

`sed` command details:

- `/^92/!` do this for the lines that don't start with `92`
- `/0|^/`: Match first 0 or start position of a line
- `/92/`: Replace with `92` at start position

An equivalent `awk` would be:

```
awk '!/^92/ {sub(/0|^/, "92")} 1' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With just bash parameter expansion:

```sh
$ while IFS= read -r line; do printf '92%s\n' "${line#0}"; done < test.txt
923333333333
923848123249
```

`${line#0}` removes a leading zero only if it exists.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '{$0=substr($0,1,1)==0?"92" substr($0,2):"92" $0} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `awk`'s `substr` function to get sub strings from current line. In main program of `awk` re-assigning values to current line(`$0`) based on conditions. Checking condition if 1st character is `0` then make `$0` value to `92` and rest of line from 2nd character ELSE add 92 before `$0`. Finally mentioning `1` will print current edited/non-edited line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer a solution with a safety check :

- (Confirmed working on `gawk 5.11` + `mawk 1.3.4` + `mawk 1.9.9.6` +
  macOS `nawk`)

```
      [nmg]awk '(/[1-9]/)*sub("^0?",92)'
```

Reason being, a solution such as `awk '!/^92/ {sub(/0|^/, "92")} 1'` mentioned above would result in extra empty rows as well as rows with only zeros getting the 92 (unless that's the desired effect))

i.e.

```
03333333333
3848123249

0
```

becomes

```
923333333333
923848123249
92
92
```

If you wanna trim out *all leading zeros* (instead of just 1 of them, and only want lines with non-zero numbers, and don't care for `nawk` at all, then it's simpler :

```
mawk2 '/[1-9]/*sub("^0*",92)'

or

mawk2 '(1<NF)*sub("^0*",92)' FS='[1-9]'
```